# Trying to get property of non-object - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-5, view

im trying to create a simple 'active page' method in laravel 5.1. Somehow i've done this before but it just doesn't want to work this time around. I KNOW its something simple because I did it very similar before its annoying me please help!

**The Code - PagesController**

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function home()
    {
        $active = [
            'home' => 'active',
            'tasks'=> ''
        ];
        return view('pages.home')->with('active', $active);
        }
    }
```

Simple enough made an array with two values and on the view i just use this

**Homepage**

```
<div class="{{ $active->home }}">Homepage</div>
<div class="{{ $active->tasks }}">Tasks</div>
```

So thats basically it..

**The Error**

"Trying to get property of non-object" Not sure why its saying this but i assume its asomething to do with the way i made the array or.. something..? all help and feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$active is an array, so you need to access it as an array.

For example, to access $active->home , you need to do $active['home']

Answer (score 2):

**Trying to get property of non-object** means you're... trying to get property of non-object :) **$active** is an array, so you need to access its elements as array:

```
<div class="{{ $active['home'] }}">Homepage</div>
<div class="{{ $active['tasks'] }}">Tasks</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you're passing array inside array ,
Yo must use dd(your var to see object composition)

```
return view('pages.home')->with($active);
```

And then acces {{$home}}